# Review test - Imperative PSQ

Tags: discussion, review-audit

[image: Test]

So apparently imperative PSQs are acceptable, (even more than that, they are high quality posts).

I'm pro-PSQ, that's why I let it open. Despite that, as far as I know, the community is anti-PSQ, so I should have failed the test.

What is after all the community's official stance on this?

**Edit:** Following up on the comments below, it seems that officially MSE is anti-PSQ, so why this contradictory audit?

Comment: What would constitute an official stance? Do we have a legislature, a court system, a constitution?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I consider as official whatever is in the FAQ. I was sure the anti-PSQ policy was stated in the FAQ, but I can't find it.

Comment: Hurkyl seemed to have found something when you asked this question in May --- see the comments on your question, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/psq-and-the-faq

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks.

Comment: The audit system is imperfect. See the discussion in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10899/5676

Comment: To show the other side of this, [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VWlTC.png) is an audit I failed by attempting to close as needing more context, when the system thinks it is a 'high quality post'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The auditor is a robot who does not follow the nuances of meta.MSE debates, and, I'm afraid, does not even read the FAQ. It uses machine-readable metadata associated with posts (edit/closure/deletion history,  votes, etc), hides it from the user being audited, and checks whether the user's reaction aligns with the actual fate of the post.

The particular post was well received, as many PSQs are. Hence, your decision to leave it open pleased the robo-auditor.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the community is to blame for upvoting that question (me included).

Comment: @GitGud: Why assign blame? The fate of that question simply shows that the community does not have a uniform standard.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have a very strong tendency towards following rules and apparently I don't comply with them in this case.

Comment: @GitGud: As far as I’m concerned, there is no such rule.